# Phalcon Debug doesn't do anything

Tags: php, phalcon

I have just started getting into Phalcon, however I have a problem with error displays and all sorts of error handling.

In my bootstrap file I have

```
$listener = new \Phalcon\Debug();
$listener->listen();
```

Which doesn't seem to generate anything. I have explicitly coded an error like so:

```
public function indexAction() {
    $recentPackages = Package::find(1,2,3,
                array(
                    "order" => "updated DESC",
                    "limit" => 10)
    );
    $this->view->setVar("recentPackages", $recentPackages);
}
```

However, the error that comes out is simply a white page with :

```
Wrong number of parameters
```

I am running Phalcon 1.2.4. Is there something else I am missing? I followed the documentation [here](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/debug.html#debug-component), but can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to remove the try/catch from your public/index.php

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/debug.html

In your public/index.php file
change value in `cactch(\Exception $e) {...HERE...}`

For example from phalconphp.com doc.

```
try {

    //... app code ...

} catch(\Exception $e) {
    echo get_class($e), ": ", $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    echo " File=", $e->getFile(), "\n";
    echo " Line=", $e->getLine(), "\n";
    echo $e->getTraceAsString();
}
```